# Not being able to remove docker images with "docker image prune -a"

Tags: docker

I have two docker images that I would like to remove, but it seems that they cannot be removed with `docker image prune -a`. Why? The two images are not used in the terminal, since I just restarted the terminal.

```
(base) ~ % docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
test_docker         latest              245e34778213        10 minutes ago      1.34GB
<none>              <none>              02f2aa7b08bb        41 minutes ago      1.21GB
(base) ~ % docker image prune -a
WARNING! This will remove all images without at least one container associated to them.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Total reclaimed space: 0B
```

How can I remove the images?

Comment: Restarting the terminal does nothing to containers, run `docker ps -a` to see which containers still exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make sure all Docker containers are stopped and removed, after that you can remove the Docker images.

Stop and remove all docker containers and images:

1. List all containers (only IDs) `docker ps -aq`.
2. Stop all running containers. `docker stop $(docker ps -aq)`
3. Remove all containers. `docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`
4. Remove all images. `docker rmi $(docker images -q)`
   or `docker image prune -a`

Answer (score 1):

`docker image prune` only remove images not currently associated with a container.

You may want to use `docker rmi [image id]` (example `docker rmi 245e34778213`) instead.